# Fubini's rectangle over unbounded rectangles

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus, improper-integrals, multiple-integral

If we are integrating $f(x,y)$ over $R = (-\infty,\infty) \times (-\infty,\infty)$, would it be right to say:

$$\iint_{R} f(x,y) \thinspace \mathrm{d}A = \lim_{\lambda \to \infty} \displaystyle{\int_{-\lambda}^{\lambda}\left( \int_{-\lambda}^{\lambda} f(x,y)\thinspace \mathrm{d}y \right) \mathrm{d}x} = \lim_{\lambda \to \infty} \displaystyle{\int_{-\lambda}^{\lambda}\left( \int_{-\lambda}^{\lambda} f(x,y)\thinspace \mathrm{d}x \right) \mathrm{d}y} $$

(as long as $f(x,y)$ is Lebesgue integrable over $R$, Fubini's theorem applies and, provided that the limit exists)?

Or is this not good practice/does it not work all the time? Would it be better to have four different dummy variables and 4 limits?

Comment: If $f$ is integrable on $\mathbb R^{2}$ this is correct. But your $R$ is strange. You seem to introduce four points at $\infty$ in the plane!

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Hi! I'm not exactly sure what you mean. I'm intending to integrate over the entire xy plane (e.g. as you might with the Gaussian integral)

Comment: The entire $xy$ plane is $(-\infty, \infty) \times (-\infty, \infty)$ and not $[-\infty, \infty] \times [-\infty, \infty]$

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Ah! Sorry my bad. I'll edit the question now. My suggested method would work for the entire x-y plane though?

Comment: Yes, it does work.

Comment: Ok perfect thanks